# mysql select count from rows with same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im using mysql and php.

i have 2 tables.

'school' table contains : student_id , product_id, student_Name
'products' table contains: product_id, product_name

i did a query

```
select  student_id, p.product_name as product_name, p.product_id
from school s join products p on s.product_id = p.product_id
```

and results shown as follows:

```
student_id  | p_name | p_id

0001        | boots  | p1

0001        | boots  | p1

0001        | boots  | p1

0001        | boots  | p1

0002        | boots  | p1

0003        | boots  | p1

0001        | shorts | p2

0001        | shorts | p2

0001        | shorts | p2

0003        | jeans  | p3
```

i need to count the number of products bought by the student but how do i further query such that i can achieve like the following below:

```
student_id | p_name | count

0001       | boots  | 4

0002       | boots  | 1

0003       | boots  | 1

0001       | shorts | 3

0003       | jeans  | 1
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select student_id, p.product_name as product_name, count(*) as count
from school s 
join products p on s.product_id = p.product_id
group by student_id, p.product_name
```